# Is there something I am not seeing or why is my code not working as it should?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I have a question:

With this `while` loop I only get this output: `XXX`

```
#include <unistd.h>

void print(int x, int y) {
    while (y > 2) {
        while ((x - 1) > 1) {
            write(1, "X", 1);
            x--;
        }
        y--;
    }
 }

int main(void) {
    print(5, 5);
    return (0);
}
```

But shouldn't it be this:

```
XXX
XXX
XXX
```

Comment: Compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand the behavior of your program. Indent it with [GNU indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/)

Comment: Once `x` reaches `2` it stays there. The next `y` loop has `x` with value `2` so the "2nd" `x` loop does not run

Comment: after the string of `X`s is printed, need to print a `\n` to move the cursor to the start of the next row

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting x after it reaches 2. The problem is that when the inner while loop finishes, x is equal to 2 (so x-1 is 1 and the inner loop ends), and by not setting it to the previous value, the other outer loop is basically useless.

The correct code to get the output "XXX XXX XXX" is something like the one below:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

void print(int x, int y) {
    int c = x;
    while(y > 2) {
        while((x - 1) > 1) {
            write(1, "X", 1);
            x--;
        }
        write(1, " ", 1);
        x = c;
        y--;
    }
 }

int main(void) {
    print(5,5);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank u soo much man!! now i understand were the problem was!!